# Phaser 3 (Typescript) Property 'start' does not exist on type 'Scene'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm unable to switch scenes in Phaser 3 (I've tried scene.switch and scene.start), but none of these appear to be methods on Phaser.Scene in Phaser 3. How do you change scenes in Phaser 3? Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I cannot find any alternative methods. Thank you!

```
// My Game entry point

    HomePage.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        scale: {
          mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
        },
        parent: 'game',
        scene: [MazeScene, MainScene],
        physics: {
          default: 'matter',
          matter: {
            debug: false,
            gravity: {
              y: 0.0,
              x: 0.0,
            },
          },
        },
      };
      this.phaserGame = new Phaser.Game(this.config);
    });
```

I have tried both `scene.start('main')`,and `scene.swap('main')`, but both of these methods do not seem to appear in the Phaser.Scene class in Phaser 3.

Answer (score 0):

As it turn out you need to reference the scene from sys.game.scene. This is what ultimately worked for me.
`this.scene.sys.game.scene.switch('mazeScene', 'mainScene')`